# Python Environment Variables Through Reflection

Tags: python, reflection, python-3.7

In Python 3.7, I wrote an `Environment` helper class which allows me to load OS environment variables through reflection.  It also converts the environment variable into a native bool or tuple, based on type hints declared in a derived class.

It works, but the linter in Visual Studio Code gives me this problem report:

> Class `'Environment'` has no `'__annotations__'` member

Here is the helper class.

```
import os
from abc import ABC

class Environment(ABC):

    @classmethod
    def from_os(cls):
        convert = {
            bool: lambda d: d == "1",
            (): lambda d: tuple(d.split(',')),
            str: lambda d: d
        }
        values = [ 
            convert[value](os.environ[key]) 
            for key,value in cls.__annotations__.items() 
            ]
        return cls(*values)
```

Again, the code actually works.  What can I do to make Pylint happy?  Perhaps there is a different way I can iterate over the attributes (and attribute type hints) in order to achieve the same result without using `__annotations__`?

I can make the linter stop complaining by cheating and adding a pylint suppression hint:

```
   for key,value in cls.__annotations__.items() # pylint: disable=no-member
```

...but that is not the solution I'm looking for.

In case it helps, here is an example of how my helper class is used to fetch an arbitrary set of environment variables:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class FWMonitoringEnv(Environment):
    # The names of these attributes are used
    # to find and load a corresponding environment variable.
    # This happens when "FWMonitoringEnv.from_os()" is called.
    preempt : bool
    split_routes : bool
    tag_key : str
    vpc_summary_route : str
    route_table_id : str
    fw_trust_enis : ()
    fw_mgmt_ips : ()
    api_key_name : str
    region : str
```

Elsewhere in the code I simply execute this:

```
env = FWMonitoringEnv.from_os()
```

While I'm at it, there is another code hygiene issue I'd like to fix.  Is there a way I can make my `Environment` class force the derived class to be a `@dataclass`?  For example, could that be accomplished with Python 3.7 type hints?

Comment: Would it be enough to do a check along the lines of `[ 
            convert[value](os.environ[key]) 
            for key,value in cls.__annotations__.items()]  if __annotations__ in cls else "some default value"` ?

Edited after I had time to test the syntax

Comment: @Lightning I want the code to succeed at its purpose, rather than throw an exception or return blank values.  The pylint `no-member` warning makes me nervous that I'm doing something that is unstable.  Of course it could simply be that pylint needs to undergo a few revs to catch up with all the nuance of Python 3.7.  Not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature method to get all class annotations.

Example

```
pprint(inspect.signature(cls).parameters)

mappingproxy(OrderedDict([('preempt', <Parameter "preempt: bool">),
                          ('split_routes', <Parameter "split_routes: bool">),
                          ('tag_key', <Parameter "tag_key: str">),
                          ('vpc_summary_route',
                           <Parameter "vpc_summary_route: str">),
                          ('route_table_id', <Parameter "route_table_id: str">),
                          ('fw_trust_enis', <Parameter "fw_trust_enis: ()">),
                          ('fw_mgmt_ips', <Parameter "fw_mgmt_ips: ()">),
                          ('api_key_name', <Parameter "api_key_name: str">),
                          ('region', <Parameter "region: str">)]))
```

When incorporated into your code, it then looks as follows:

```
    def from_os(cls):
        convert = {
            bool: lambda d: d == '1',
            (): lambda d: tuple(d.split(',')),
            str: lambda d: d
        }
        values = [ 
            convert[val.annotation](os.environ[val.name]) 
            for val in signature(cls).parameters.values()
            ]
        return cls(*values)
```

I believe it is a better way to get it "true" way :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just do it using `getattr`

```
getattr(cls, "__annotations__").items()
```

And the whole source code block

```
import os
from abc import ABC

class Environment(ABC):

    @classmethod
    def from_os(cls):
        convert = {
            bool: lambda d: d == "1",
            (): lambda d: tuple(d.split(',')),
            str: lambda d: d
        }
        values = [ 
            convert[value](os.environ[key]) 
            for key,value in getattr(cls, "__annotations__").items() 
            ]
        return cls(*values)
```

> This will make the linter happy and your code working :) Also it is a good idea to add an assertion check that the `cls` class has the required magic field `__annotations__`.

Comment: I appreciate this honest stab at a fix.  However, I'm looking for a solution that "truly" solves the problem rather than sweeping it under the rug.  Resorting to getattr(...) is basically no better than me using `# pylint: disable=no-member`.  In fact, if I'm going to simply "hide" the problem, then I prefer `# pylint: disable=no-member` because it becomes self-documenting code indicating an anomaly I'm dealing with.  Finally, if `__annotations__` is not present then I definitely want an unhandled exception to be thrown (which would be the current behavior).

Comment: check my other answer, I don't want to remove the second one because they are quite different for the case